# Insert command result into vim command

Tags: vim

I'd like to find and replace some text with other text which consist the result of the shell command. This is my trial, which is not working:

```
:40,43s/'height': 650/'height': system('python -c "import random; print(random.randint(500, 600))"')/g
```

Vim don't want to evaluate `system('python -c "import random; print(random.randint(500, 600)')` part.

Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "shell command" is not correct!

- you should at least check if those quotes (`'` and `"`) in your command are paired
- you should at least check if all brackets `(..)` in your command are paired.

For the vim `:s` command, you should use `\=` to get the result of an expression. Read `:h :s\=` for details.

Your example:

```
:40,43s/\v('height':) 650/\=submatch(1)." ".system('python -c "import random; print(random.randint(500, 600))"')/
```

Your command was fixed in above line.

Comment: Just a little edit to remove trailing newline when command returns a number:
`:68,77s/\v('height':) 650/\=submatch(1)." ".system('python -c "import random; print(random.randint(500, 600))"')[:-2]/`